# appendChild is not a function, cant add text to multi divs

Tags: javascript, dom

In my case I have 8 divs and I want to dynamically via javascript add text to each of these. When I do that with using querySelector (for one div) it works, but for querySelectorAll (each of these) it doesn't. 
code:

```
html
            <div class=" bookapp__container">
                    <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
                    <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
                    <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
                    <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
                    <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
                    <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
                    <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
                    <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
            </div>
```

```
javascript

let myParagraph = document.createElement('p');
myParagraph.innerHTML = 'Some text';
let myItems = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
myItems.appendChild(myParagraph);
```

Answer (score 0):

you'll have to loop through `myItem` instead of trying to use appendChild on that.

```
myItems.forEach(item => item.appendChild(myParagraph))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works.

Answer (score 0):

`querySelectorAll` returns a collection so you need to iterate over that and append child. Also note a node cannot have multiple parent, so you need to create new `p` during each iteration

```js
document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach((item) => {
  let myParagraph = document.createElement('p');
  myParagraph.innerHTML = 'Some text';
  item.appendChild(myParagraph);
})
```

```html
<div class=" bookapp__container">
  <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
  <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
  <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
  <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
  <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
  <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
  <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
  <div class="bookapp__container__item item"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works.